# "at" vs. "in" [as descriptor of situation or condition]

Tags: meaning, prepositions

one of the meaning of 'at' is this:

> In the state or condition of

e.g.

> The country at war

And also one of the meaning of 'in' is this:

> To or at a situation or condition of

e.g.

> I am in love

**BUT** the big question is what is the difference between them for this meaning?

How to know which of them is appropriate for our sentences to use?

Is there any grammatical point?

Answer (score 1):

["At vs In"](http://www.learnenglish.de/mistakes/atvsin.html)

This link was very useful while trying to figure out a general rule for something I use  every day.

> In, as a preposition of place, is usually used to talk about the position of someone or something inside large places such as countries, continents, big cities etc.

So the use of "in" has more of a general sense behind it.

> At, as a preposition of place, is usually used to talk about the position of someone or something inside small and unimportant places such as villages, small towns etc.

Where "at" helps to fill out the specifics.

Comment: Thanks for reply but we are talking about situations/conditions not places. Can you tell us which one of these are bigger? love or war? :) that's the point!